# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to push the excel `xlsx` data to `mySQl Alchemy` by using this simple code...

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy


mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

# MySQL Connection
MYSQL_USER = 'xxxxxxx'
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxx'
MYSQL_HOST_IP = '127.0.0.1'
MYSQL_PORT = 3306
MYSQL_DATABASE = 'xlsx_test_db'

# connect db
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://' + MYSQL_USER + ':' + MYSQL_PASSWORD + '@' + MYSQL_HOST_IP + ':' + str(
    MYSQL_PORT) + '/' + MYSQL_DATABASE, echo=False)
engine.connect()

# reading and insert one file at a time
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    # only process excels files
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
    if extension == 'xlsx':

        df = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027.xlsx', sheet_name='Report')
        df.to_sql(file_basename, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

But I found this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/automateDB/myWatchDog.py", line 28, in <module>
    df.to_sql(file_basename, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2532, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 460, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1173, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 577, in create
    self.pd_sql.drop_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1222, in drop_table
    self.meta.reflect(only=[table_name], schema=schema)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyALLRefProf\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3956, in reflect
    (bind.engine, s, ', '.join(missing)))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine(mysql+mysqlconnector://root:***@127.0.0.1:3306/xlsx_test_db): (MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027)
```

So any one could me to solve this...

Thank you...

I hope it would be clear enough....

Comment: Did you try that? `df.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace')`

Comment: @E. Zeytinci I tried this and got the same error

Comment: use lower case for name is okay.

Answer (score 38):

Changing the table name to lower case worked for me.

Comment: Good point! Important to keep in mind that tables which in SQL might be written as all caps are outside represented in all lowercase.

Comment: I spend two hours to find the problem but failed until I saw this solution. So weird!!!

Comment: Worked also for me for Oracle DB

Comment: What if you want the table names to actually be set in uppercase?

Comment: What worked for me was to keep it as it is: "the_TABLE_name"! Using "the_table_name" or "THE_TABLE_NAME" were returning same error when tried to dump the data.

Answer (score 4):

if you have MySQL installed into windows you have to use **lowercase** for the **name of table**s.

Answer (score 4):

I used upper case for if_exists = 'append' and it works but not for 'replace' .
'replace' only works with lower case, which makes no sense

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29892574)

Comment: This is correct for snowflake. I tried uppercase table name for replace but it fails. If I lowercase the table name it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This could result from a view with the same name that already exists in the db.
I `DROP VIEW <view_name>` and the error was solved.