# InvalidRequestError when reading view but not SQL query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy engine (`type(engine)` outputs `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>`), when I run this snippet I get an error:

```
with engine.connect() as connexion:
    pd.read_sql_table("MY_VIEW", connexion, schema="abc")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\my_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 340, in read_sql_table
    table = pandas_sql.read_table(
  File "c:\my_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1627, in read_table
    self.meta.reflect(bind=self.con, only=[table_name])
  File "c:\my_project\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 5530, in reflect
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in 
Engine(mssql+pyodbc://username:***@myserver.database.windows.net,1433/mydb?driver=ODBC+DRIVER+17+for+SQL+Server) 
schema 'abc': (MY_VIEW)
```

But when I try to query all lines, this works:

```
pd.read_sql_query("select * from [abc].[MY_VIEW]", engine)

[...]

[4742 rows x 18 columns]
```

As per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60906045/8947333) I tried to put the view name in lowercase, but it did not change anything.

I can however request any table that is not a view with `pd.read_sql_table`, but this method fails with any view on any schema.

Do you have an idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: What versions of pandas and SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: I'm using pandas==2.0.3 and SQLAlchemy==2.0.7

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest versions of SQLAlchemy and pandas. Your code works fine for me with SQLA version 2.0.21 and pandas version 2.1.1.